# Get data from a table in Azure database

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to get data from the table I have created in Microsoft Azure.

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$db));
```

When I connect with the code above, it works. Because I put conditions

```
if($conn === false){
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
if($conn == true){
echo "hi!";
}
```

and it returns true and prints "hi!".

But when I try to get data from the table course, it fails.

```
$cek=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT ID FROM course");
```

Because after the $cek query, I put such control;

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cek);
echo "</pre>";
if(!$cek)
{echo "Fail!";}
```

and it gives such error;

```
Resource id #2
Fail!
```

How can I manage this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sqlsrv_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) function returns a statement resource.

> Returns a statement resource on success

So we need to extract the data from the resource using a function like [sqlsrv_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

```
$data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cek);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you Machavity. Now I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Machavity, actually I want to modify your answer to the algorithm I've written. Can you take a look to the link I've pasted my algorithm? http://codepaste.net/a2jgfy

Comment: There isn't a `fetch_assoc` in sqlsrv http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php. Use `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. Looks good otherwise

Comment: Thank you Machavity, I'm trying now.

Comment: It's approaching to the right one. :) Now at least the "for" loop works. It gave the error;Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail!
Fail! :) Now what can you prefer to do? :)

Comment: Instead of echoing Fail, try adding this in there `print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)`

Comment: I don't understand. There is an existing table, I've already created. But why it fails to fetch data?

Comment: Your problem at this point is with the SQL statement itself or the connection. It's outside the scope of what we can do here